# Textbox Email Validation

Tags: vb.net

Hi the problem im having is that im trying to validate a text box to make sure an email address was entered...
I copied someone elses code and then changed it to suit my program.. however even when a valid email is entered is still says invalid email entry

```
Private Sub EmailTextBox_Validating(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles EmailTextBox.Validating
    Dim temp As String
    temp = EmailTextBox.Text
    Dim conditon As Boolean
    emailaddresscheck(temp)
    If emailaddresscheck(conditon) = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter your email address correctly", "Incorrect Email Entry")
        EmailTextBox.Text = ""
        EmailTextBox.BackColor = Color.Blue
    Else
        EmailTextBox.BackColor = Color.Green
    End If

End Sub


Private Function emailaddresscheck(ByVal emailaddress As String) As Boolean
    Dim pattern As String = "^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$"
    Dim emailAddressMatch As Match = Regex.Match(emailaddress, pattern)
    If emailAddressMatch.Success Then
        emailaddresscheck = True
    Else
        emailaddresscheck = False
    End If
End Function

Private Sub EmailTextBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles EmailTextBox.TextChanged
    EmailTextBox.BackColor = Color.White
    Dim temp As String
    temp = EmailTextBox.Text
    Dim conditon As Boolean
    emailaddresscheck(temp)
    : If emailaddresscheck(conditon) = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter your email address correctly", "Incorrect Email Entry")
        EmailTextBox.Text = ""
        EmailTextBox.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    Else
        EmailTextBox.BackColor = Color.Green
    End If
End Sub
```

The colours used were green and yellow but I changed the colours of the boxes to identify were the problem was.. the box appears blue so the error ...im assuming is somwere in this snipit of code.

```
Private Function emailaddresscheck(ByVal emailaddress As String) As Boolean
    Dim pattern As String = "^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$"
    Dim emailAddressMatch As Match = Regex.Match(emailaddress, pattern)
    If emailAddressMatch.Success Then
        emailaddresscheck = True
    Else
        emailaddresscheck = False
    End If
End Function
```

Thanks in advance.. :) x

Comment: I like your regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the following code, I have changed a bit of it

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        TextBox1.BackColor = Color.White
        Dim temp As String
        temp = TextBox1.Text
        'Dim conditon As Boolean = False
        If emailaddresscheck(temp) = True Then
            ': If emailaddresscheck(conditon) = True Then
            TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Green
        Else
            'MessageBox.Show("Please enter your email address correctly", "Incorrect Email Entry")
            'TextBox1.Text = ""
            TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        End If

    End Sub
```

I have stopped the message cause it will never allow to enter valid email unless you copy and paste.

Also try this pattern

```
Dim pattern As String = "\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
```

Comment: In your code: 'If emailaddresscheck(temp) = True Then', '= True' is redundant.

Answer (score 6):

An easy way to check if an email address is valid is to try creating a MailAddress from it:

```
Try
    Dim testAddress = New MailAddress(email)
Catch ex As FormatException
    ' not a valid email address
End Try
```

Since .NET 5, there is a [MailAddress.TryCreate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddress.trycreate) method which doesn't rely on throwing an exception if the supplied string could not be parsed as an email address:

```
Dim emailAddress As MailAddress
If MailAddress.TryCreate(email, emailAddress) Then
    ' emailAddress contains an email address
Else
    ' the string email is not an email address
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

you are giving the message box in a wrong condition, otherwise your code is correct.
Just change coding as below.

```
If emailaddresscheck(conditon) = True Then
           msgbox ("Correct email id")
Else
   MessageBox.Show("Please enter your email address correctly", "Incorrect Email Entry")
    EmailTextBox.Text = ""

End If
```

**For reference:**

```
Function EmailAddressCheck(ByVal emailAddress As String) As Boolean

        Dim pattern As String = "^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$"
        'Dim pattern As String = "\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
        Dim emailAddressMatch As Match = Regex.Match(emailAddress, pattern)
        If emailAddressMatch.Success Then
            EmailAddressCheck = True
        Else
            EmailAddressCheck = False
        End If

End Function

Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        'EmailAddressCheck(TextBox6.Text)
        If EmailAddressCheck(TextBox6.Text) = True Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter your email address correctly", "Incorrect Email Entry")
            TextBox6.Text = ""
        Else
            MsgBox("correct")
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: plz put all your code examples, in code spacers, there is the curly bracers ("{}") in the edit mode

Answer (score 0):

P

```
rivate Function validateEmail(ByVal Email As String)
        Try
            Dim myEmails As String() = Email.Split(",")
            Dim isV As Boolean = True
            For i As Integer = 0 To myEmails.Length - 1
                ' Validate One by Ibe
                isV = Global.ValidateEmail.IsValidEmail(myEmails(i).ToString)
                If (isV = False) Then
                    Return False
                End If
            Next
            Return isV
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Function
```

1. Pass your email address as string, this is simple and easy. It will return a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I search over internet and I was looking for simple Answer few cods to get the Job Done. the code depend on VB.net
First you have import this regex.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Private Sub TXTEmail_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TXTEmail.Leave
        
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+[@][a-z]+[\.][a-z]{2,3}")  

Dim isValid As Boolean = regex.IsMatch(TXTEmail.Text.Trim)
        If Not isValid Then
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Email")
            TXTEmail.Select()

        End If
    End Sub
```

Or Type this original come with

```
New Regex("^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$")
```

I put this code in text leaving event. you can add it at any condition as a button to check it but for me best result is when I leave the text I want to show the error massage.

plus I go deeper to learn Regex to platform at any condition password check you named it and I found this On YouTube :
REGEX (REGULAR EXPRESSIONS) WITH EXAMPLES IN DETAIL | Regex Tutorial

https://youtu.be/9RksQ5YT7FM?list=LL